# Bridging connection between HoloLens2 and a computer running on ROS2 Foxy

Tags: ros2, computer-vision, dds

I wanted to consider using HoloLens2 for my project using ROS2. But before buying one, I was hoping to ask around if someone already tried using ROS2 FastDDS to make Hololens2 communicate with a computer running on ROS2 Foxy. I never started anything yet, but I hope you can refer me to any recommended documentation that could get me started.

Thank you in advance.